# Nested Horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nested, recyclerview-layout, nestedrecyclerview

I wanna create a nested RecyclerView were the Parent RV is horizontal layout manager with > 3 items and the child is horzinotl too, but I can't scroll the child it's only indicate the parent gesture.

Parent LayoutManager

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    listItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    listItem.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Child LayoutManager

```
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

XML - Parent

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

XML - Parent Item

```
     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/roundColor_svprogresshuddefault"
    android:elevation="160dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/home_cell_margin">


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/list_item"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML - Child

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listHolder">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" ></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result Example

[image: Example]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Edited and added. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a simple custom RecyclerView and below the final code

```
public class DJHRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public DJHRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DJHRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DJHRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```